# How to Add Images in Select drop down in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my code but it is not working. Here I am attaching the screen-shot of our tool, in the second column we have to get image drop down and if we click on the particular image that image has to be updated on the google map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Please post question with necessary code or else we are not able to help. Thank you

Comment: We need more information than what is given in the post. Post some code, and a longer description on how the page works, and more information about the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about your use case but if you want to add images in dropdown list there is simple light weight plugin call ddSlick, [here is link](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo)
please add more description if you want to do something else or more .